# Placing div side by side in a for loop - CSS styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a div inside a for loop and placing them on the document. 2 divs are to be placed side by side and the following 2 divs below them and so on.

Can someone suggest me what would be the css styling for this case?
Here is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < piechartDataArray.length; i++) {

        var elementID = 'piechart' + (i+1).toString();
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.id = elementID;
        document.body.appendChild(element);

      if (i%2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById(elementID).style.width=...                 
   }else{
         document.getElementById(elementID).style.width=... 
        }
}
```

Comment: What does the JavaScript have to do with your question about CSS layout?

Comment: So...Basically you're asking how to do a two column layout in css?

Comment: He wants to create something different then others i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
<div class="some-class"></div>
<div class="some-class"></div>
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

And assuming this desired layout:

```
|  |  |
-------
|  |  |
```

I'd use this CSS:

```
div.some-class {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: With this approach I think he don't need to care about the condition he applied in if else block.. The CSS will take care of it if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use the CSS3 Column methods:

```js
piechartDataArray = [1,2,3,4];

for (var i = 0; i < piechartDataArray.length; i++) {

        var elementID = 'piechart' + (i+1).toString();
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.id = elementID;
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(element);
}
```

```css
div{
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 
}

#container{
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each div set width=50% and float:left

Comment: Floats should often be a last resort. They cause as many issues as they solve. Read more: http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts